# UWP trigger command on keydown?

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, command-pattern

I am trying to execute a command when the user presses a key:

```
   <TextBox Command="{Binding myCommand}" Height="200" Width="200" FontSize="20"></TextBox>
```

Now using UWP im not entirely sure how this is accomplished. In WPF we have keybindings but here? If possible without third party libraries. How would you guys solve this? I prefer not to reinvent the wheel and create my own command implementation that works for edge cases like these.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Install the Behaviors NuGet if you don't have it and then:

```
<TextBox Height="200" Width="200" FontSize="20">  
    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="KeyDown">
            <Core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding myCommand}" />
        </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors> 
</TextBox>
```

Comment: How comes its not part of the core .net package and has to be installed through NuGet? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I guess some people don't apply MVVM and thus don't need this. Also, many developers use other popular frameworks that implement behaviors, e.g. MVVM Light and some even use their own proprietary solution.

Comment: still weird dont you think? I thought wpf and uwp were mvvm frameworks yet they keep things like win2d and behaviors as seperare packages omg.

Comment: WPF and UWP are not MVVM frameworks. You can develop them entirely using code behind. Of course is not the best practice. Personally I think is a good choice not to include this by default in the core as many developers use something else and they would have to remove it.

Comment: My bad, I meant presentation frameworks with mvvm possibilities. I understand, so its more of a choice to make things more modular then. I guess it is good after all to be given the choice what to use and to leave out.

Comment: Managed, Native is for c++ projects

Comment: Yep, just saw it. Thanks a lot for your help. Wish I could give you more points : )

Comment: That was a mistake...I accidently clicked on the other answer. Waiting an hour to give you the bounty which was thought for the other guy who really helped me out a lot. I dont care about reputation though, as long as I get to learn.

Comment: @Asperger In your previous comment under this post you wrote *"Wish I could give you more points*". Well, now your wish becomes a reality :)

Comment: @IvanStoev yep he gets them now :D